# Why is my trendline not appearing in my plot?

Tags: r

I am trying to add a trendline into my scatterplot in R with ggplot2.

```
 > ggplot(df_scatter, aes(x=new_cases, y=people_fully_vaccinated,color=Country)) + geom_point()+ geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

I am able to get the scatterplot with different points color relative to the country, but my trendline is no where to be seen on the graph.

```
 dput(df_scatter) >
 structure(list(Country = c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", 
 "Canada", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czechia", "Denmark", "Estonia", 
 "Finland", "France", "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Israel", 
 "Italy", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Netherlands", 
 "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", 
 "Sweden", "Switzerland", "United Kingdom", "United States"), 
 new_cases = c(1051.966, 1041.493, 468.778, 58.396, 1206.863, 
  487.72, 2123.911, 746.22, 618.78, 196.094, 451.496, 676.551, 
 588.304, 734.712, -123.668, 166.381, 692.579, 696.318, 250.467, 
 1341.75, 278.102, 527.423, 251.772, 2028.668, 1632.733, 144.977, 
 376.47, 729.161, 630.726, 278.176), hosp_patients_per_million = 
c(212.207, 
213.113, 1185.792, 43.922, 452.757, 94.866, 370.272, 59.519, 
395.416, 46.14, 105.248, 534.245, 72.81, 116.799, 21.502, 
68, 582.774, 631.631, 89.79, 86.531, 34.763, 359.103, 45.732, 
43.584, 476.254, 41.63, 26.968, 116, 118.58, 139.567), 
people_fully_vaccinated = c(64.74, 
74.49, 24.86, 75.92, 46.7, 64.78, 58.56, 76.43, 59.06, 72.04, 
69.16, 60.29, 81.68, 75.92, 62.08, 72.7, 61.89, 65.68, 65.91, 
73.74, 69.54, 53.7, 87.78, 42.82, 54.86, 80.34, 68.95, 65.07, 
67.72, 57.83)), row.names = c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", 
"Canada", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czechia", "Denmark", "Estonia", 
"Finland", "France", "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Israel", 
"Italy", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Netherlands", 
"Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", 
"Sweden", "Switzerland", "United Kingdom", "United States"), class = 
c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you provide some reproducible example. You may use `dput(df_scatter)` and paste the result to your question.

Comment: Each country has only one sample.(Take a look at `table(df_scatter$Country)`). That's why there is no regression line exists. Does trend line do not need to by Country?

Comment: Yup, you are right, after removing the aes(color=Country), I am able to plot a trend line. But I wish to add color by Country.

Comment: move the color to your geom_point: geom_point(aes(color=Country))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling R to plot a line per country - move the `aes(color=Country)` to your `geom_point()` call.

```
ggplot(df_scatter, aes(x=new_cases, y=people_fully_vaccinated)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=Country)) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df_scatter, aes(x=new_cases, y=people_fully_vaccinated)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=Country))+ 
  geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

[image]

You may specify arguments inside `aes` manually, depends on your purpose.

Comment: Hi, yup. Thank you.